# How to use fancybox button helper + fancybox thumbnail helper?

Tags: jquery, button, fancybox, thumbnails, helper

I need to use both of them simultaniously (fancybox button helper and thumbnail helper)

I can only use one of them at a time.

These are the examples of each function:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Already tried using the two classes:

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons fancybox-thumbs"
```

But it doesn't work...
only one at a time, like:

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons"
```

or

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs"
```

.

These are the javascripts of each:

```
            /*
            Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
        */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
            Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
        */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : { 
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Thanks

Comment: JFK answer works great!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need a single script to use both so with a single `class` in your `html` should work like

```
<a class="fancybox" ...
```

then the script:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 openEffect  : 'none',
 closeEffect : 'none',
 prevEffect : 'none',
 nextEffect : 'none',
 closeBtn  : false,
 arrows    : false,
 nextClick : true,
 helpers : {
  title : {
   type : 'inside'
  },
  buttons : {},
  thumbs : {
   width : 50,
   height : 50
  }
 },
 afterLoad : function() {
  this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
 }
});
```