# Fancybox hidden images and thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am new to fancybox, so I'm not to sure if this is a possibility. I have thumbnail fliers on my site that, when clicked, open a full gallery. Is it possible to incorporate thumbnail helpers in the gallery when the flyers are clicked? I know its possible for regular fancybox, but I have never seen it done with hidden gallery images.

Comment: Share some code that you tried.

Comment: yes it's possible, Just make sure you include the fancybox thumbnail helpers css and js files AND your hidden elements all share the same `rel` or `data-fancybox-group` attributes. BTW, you don't actually need to have `<img>` thumbnails in your page IF those elements are hidden, only the anchors to reduce the page load size. Check this for ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957540/1055987

Comment: BTW, you don't need to add `style='display:none;'` to ALL your links as suggested in @Ergec answer, just place all of them inside a hidden `div`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will post more code if I get stuck

Comment: I am absolutely lost, but according to the "rules" here, I am not allowed to ask for help. :(

Answer (score 2):

`fancybox` doesn't care if some of the thumbnails are hidden or not. Just put all thumbnails as a gallery and define `style='display:none;'` to all thumbnails except the first one. `fancybox` will still show all images.

Comment: the OP said `incorporate thumbnail helpers`, which are not the regular html thumbnails on their page